# Know the types of properties in an object c#

Tags: c#, reflection, types, properties

I know how to get an object properties using reflection:

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
```

now how do I know if properties[0] is a string? or maybe it is a int? how can I know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each element of `properties` will be a [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx), which has a [`PropertyType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx) property, indicating the type of the property.

So for example, you might use:

```
if (properties[0].PropertyType == typeof(string))
```

or if you wanted to check something in an inheritance-permitting way:

```
if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(properties[0].PropertyType))
```